# How to/ best way to run a test for each element found? Protractor/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor and Jasmine.

I'm automating a website that is heavily data-driven with a lot of dynamic elements (elements displayed depend on data available). As a result, I never know exactly how many elements there are, but I need to test each one since data-driven means that just because one works, doesn't mean the rest will.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this - I've done tons of research, but none of the ideas work, or only partially work.

What I've tried:

1. Throwing an it block into a loop that dynamically grabs the element count

   - I found that this doesn't work because it appears Jasmine evaluates which / how many tests run at compile. And since I need get to the page before I can grab the count, the count is always 0, so it runs the test 0 times

     - This only works with static data, but again, my data is dynamic, so this won't work. At least, I couldn't find a way to
2. Throwing an it block into a loop that loops using a variable and then reassigning the variable in a beforeAll

   - Same issue as the previous, reassigning doesn't work because Jasmine uses the value that was available on compile
3. Looping through the elements inside of an 'it' and doing an 'expect' for each element

   - This works for the most part, but only the first error gets reported. I'd ideally like to see every element that has an issue. Jasmine loops through all elements even when one expect fails, so I'm not sure why it doesn't report them all / or how to report them all

I'd prefer to use solution #3 if I can see all expect failures, but I'm open to any suggestions. If there's a better way, best practice, or a way you handle this instead of what I have listed, I'd like to hear those as well.

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Post code you had tried so far.